# Remove all packages from conda environment that are not included in environment.yml

Tags: conda, environment

Suppose I have manually added some packages to `some_environment`, which is created using `environment.yml`, how would I efficiently remove all packages that are not specified in the `environment.yml`?

One solution is to delete the environment and re-create it from the `environment.yml` however, I would expect it can be faster by only deleting those that are unused, instead of deleting everything and then re-installing the used ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conda's `--prune` is broken

The `conda env update --prune` command should do this, but I just tested it and **it does not work**. See [bug report](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7279).

**py311.yaml**

```yaml
name: py311
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python =3.11
```

**Commands**

```bash
## create the environment from YAML
conda env create -n foo -f py311.yaml

## ad hoc install a package not in YAML
conda install -n foo numpy

## attempt using the `--prune` argument to revert
conda env update --prune -n foo -f py311.yaml

## check if numpy is still installed (it shouldn't be)
conda list -n foo numpy
# packages in environment at /Users/mfansler/mambaforge-arm64/envs/foo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
# numpy                     1.24.1          py311ha92fb03_0    conda-forge


# shucks! - it's still there
```

### Mamba's `--prune` works!

Fortunately, the Mamba implementation of the `--prune` operation works as expected. Continuing from the environment above:

```bash
## install Mamba if you don't have it
# conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba

## prune with mamba
mamba env update --prune -n foo -f py311.yaml

## check that numpy is gone
mamba list -n foo numpy
# packages in environment at /Users/mfansler/mambaforge-arm64/envs/foo:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

## there's no match - great!
```

---

#### Minor Note on Explicit & Implicit Specifications

It may be worth clarifying that the request:

> "*remove all packages that are not specified in the environment.yml*"

could be interpreted as meaning all packages not *explicitly* specified. That would not be possible, since many packages also have unavoidable dependencies.

For example, even though `python=3.11` is the only *explicit* specification given above, it is impossible to have a functional Python without also including *dependencies* (*implicit* specifications). There is no mechanism to remove everything not *explicitly* specified, mostly because that would lead to a broken environment. A more precise expression for the solution presented here might be "*remove all packages not required by the explicitly specified packages*".

I only mention this because I've seen such an interpretation in the wild - not because I think this is OP's intent. Just trying to cover all the bases.