# conda won't update environment through environment.yml

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have an `environment.yml` file with the following content:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - pandas
  - matplotlib
  - control
  - scipy
  - pathlib
  - numpy
  - tomli
  - sphinx
  - furo
  - sphinx-toolbox
  - sphinx-autodoc-typehints
  - pytest
  - mypy
  - black
  - flake8
  - coverage
  - h5py
```

I created an environment named *pippo* with conda `create --name pippo python=3.10`, then I run `conda activate pippo` and finally I run `conda env update --name pippo --file environment.yml  --prune`.

The output is:

```
conda-forge/osx-arm64                                       Using cache
conda-forge/noarch                                          Using cache
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
pkgs/main/osx-arm64                                           No change
pkgs/r/osx-arm64                                              No change
Collect all metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate pippo
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate
```

whereas I expected the packages in `environment.yml` to be installed.

How to solve it?

Comment: What if you write `name: pippo` on the first line of the environment.yml file? Also, unrelated to your issue, I can highly recommend using [mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba) instead of conda as it is much faster in resolving the dependencies.

Comment: Tried and it didn't work. About mamba I have `conda config --set solver libmamba` so I guess it is the same.

Comment: Perhaps you can add `-vvv` to your conda command to increase verbosity and see any errors? I just tried the steps you listed (create environment.yml, then `conda create`  empty env, then `conda env update`) and I got an environment with the requested packages.

Comment: Hold on: the packages were actually installed. I haven't seen them downloading, so I thought they were not there but apparently they were cached somewhere so they just have been copied from a local location to the new environment. I think.

Comment: You can verify that by doing `conda activate pippo` and then `conda list` or `conda env export`.

Comment: Regarding "*I haven't seen them downloading,*", that's very well possible as conda uses a local cache when installing packages in an environment. With a standard install the packages are actually not copied over, but conda tries to use hardlinks where possible, minimizing the amount of data that is duplicated.

Comment: Good to know. I thought conda would download the whole package instead of using hardlinks (which is way more reasonable). Thanks.

Comment: This question gives no evidence that they aren't installed. Please add `conda list -n pippo` to the body of the question. Also, if pruning is an issue, be aware that `conda`'s `--prune` flag is broken, but `mamba` one works (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/75172661/570918).

Comment: @merv please, read the previous comments.

Comment: It's not clear what the final verdict was. If this is an issue of misinterpretting Conda's output, then we should close this question.

Comment: @merv if you believe that this question along with the comments is absolutely useless for the entire community, i.e. every single user knows that conda cache files and use hardlinks, then feel free to close. But please, provide a valid proof that the whole community is well aware of that.